when user drag and drop image it should display dynamically without refreshing page using ajax
When a user drags and drops an image, it should dynamically display without refreshing the page using Ajax.
When a user drags and drops multiple images, all of them should display below the form dynamically. For this, I need to use Ajax. Could anyone provide a solution for this?
